# How to stop media player start and stop media player properly in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-mediaplayer, streaming-radio

Hi am trying to stream online radio while opening my app when buffering first time it runs fine while i close the app and then start again the app it plays from where the player last closed and then stopped after it ends and i have to startup manually to stream the url for current level of radio

my coding:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DrawerLayout drawer;
    ImageView list_activity_check;
    ImageView share,speaker,mute, control;
    DrawerListAdapter drawerListAdapter;
    ListView listview_nav;

    private SmallBang mSmallBang;

    String [] Items={"Program Lists","Rate app"} ;
    int [] images={R.drawable.pro_logo,
            R.drawable.rate_icon} ;


    String[] titles = {
            "Ippadikku Idhayam",
            "Akilam 360",
            "Cine Pattarai",
            "Palsuvai Thoranam",
            "Pesum Noolagam",
            "Lollu Cafe",
            "Kavi Saagaram",
            "Aa muthal Akk",
            "Thiraicholai",
            "Kathamba Saaral",
            "Paarkatha Pakkangal",
            "Pagadi Panna Porom",

    };

    public static  final String[] fromtime = new String[]{"10:30 AM","12:30 PM","14:30 PM","16:30 PM","18:30 PM","20:30 PM","22:30 PM","00:30 AM","02:30 AM","04:30 AM","06:30 AM","08:30 AM"};

    public static  final String[] totime = new String[]{"12:30 PM","14:30 PM","16:30 PM","18:30 PM","20:30 PM","22:30 PM","00:30 AM","02:30 AM","04:30 AM","06:30 AM","08:30 AM","10:30 AM"};



    Integer[] images0 = {
            R.drawable.ipadikku_idhayam,
            R.drawable.akilam_360,
            R.drawable.cine_pattarai,
            R.drawable.palsuvai_thoranam,
            R.drawable.pesum_noolagam,
            R.drawable.lollu_cafe,
            R.drawable.kavi_saagaram,
            R.drawable.aa_muthal_akk,
            R.drawable.thiraicholai,
            R.drawable.kathamba_saaral,
            R.drawable.paarkatha_pakkangal,
            R.drawable.pagadi_panna_porom,

    };

//************* Current Show ***************//

    ListView list,lvshow;
    List<Program> rowItems;
    int  iImageId;
    String sTitle,sFrom,sTo ;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    ImageView music;
    int media1;
    int intValue1;
    AdapAdapter Adapadapter;
    ArrayList<String> iTitle = null;
    ArrayList<String> sQuantity = null;
    ArrayList<String> sQuantity1 = null;
    ArrayList<String> sImageID = null;



//***************************************//


    SeekBar seekbar;
    AudioManager audioManager;
    MediaPlayer media, mediaPlayer;
boolean playPause = false;
    boolean intialStage = true;
    int intvalue  ;

    ImageView timer;

    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    String URL = "http://streaming.shoutcast.com/MUKILFMRADIO";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addNotification();
        mSmallBang = SmallBang.attach2Window(this);

        list_activity_check = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        share = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.share);
        speaker = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.speaker);
        mute = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mute);
        control = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play);
        timer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.timer);

        //************ Current show ************//


        db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("MukilApp",Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS proname(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,ImageID INTEGER,Title TEXT,FromTiming INTEGER,ToTiming INTEGER);");

        rowItems = new ArrayList<Program>();
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            Program item = new Program(images0[i], titles[i],fromtime[i],totime[i]);
            rowItems.add(item);
        }
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM proname;");

        lvshow = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvshow);

        // listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        final ProgramAdapter adapter = new ProgramAdapter(this,rowItems, false);
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            Program rowItem = (Program) adapter.getItem(i);

            iImageId = rowItem.getImageId();
            sTitle = rowItem.getTitle();
            sFrom = rowItem.getFromtime();
            sTo = rowItem.getTotime();

            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO proname (ImageID,Title,FromTiming,ToTiming) VALUES(" + iImageId + ",'" + sTitle + "','" + sFrom + "','" + sTo + "');");

        }


        final Cursor cView = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM proname WHERE FromTiming <= time('now', 'localtime')\n" + "" +
                "AND ToTiming >= time('now', 'localtime')\n", null);
        if (cView.getCount() > 0) {

            sImageID = new ArrayList<String>();
            iTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
            sQuantity = new ArrayList<String>();
            sQuantity1 = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (cView.moveToNext()) {

                sImageID.add(cView.getString(1));
                iTitle.add(cView.getString(2));
                sQuantity.add(cView.getString(3));
                sQuantity1.add(cView.getString(4));

                Adapadapter = new AdapAdapter(this, sImageID, iTitle, sQuantity, sQuantity1);
                lvshow.setAdapter(Adapadapter);
            }

        }


        //*************************************//



        timer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSmallBang.bang(v);
                mSmallBang.setmListener(new SmallBangListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd() {

                        Intent slideactivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Timer_Activity.class);

                        Bundle bndlanimation =
                                ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.animate1, R.anim.animate2).toBundle();
//                        startActivity(slideactivity, bndlanimation);
                        startActivityForResult(slideactivity, 1001,bndlanimation);
//                finish();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    media = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.mukil_master_jingle);
        media.start();
        media.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        if (intialStage) {
            new Player()
                    .execute(URL);
        }



        intvalue = mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId();
        control.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);

        control.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (playPause == false) {
                    control.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    new Player().cancel(true);
                    media.stop();
                    media.reset();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    media.stop();

                    playPause = true;
                } else {
                    control.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
                    if (intialStage) {
                        new Player()
                                .execute(URL);
                    } else {
                        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                    playPause = false;
                }

            }
        });

        speaker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                speaker.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mute.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                media.setVolume(0, 0);
                mediaPlayer.setVolume(0, 0);

                speaker.setImageResource(R.drawable.speaker);
                mSmallBang.bang(v);
                mSmallBang.setmListener(new SmallBangListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd() {

                    }


                });

            }
        });
        mute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                speaker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mute.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                media.setVolume(1, 1);
                mediaPlayer.setVolume(1, 1);

            }
        });


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); // hide built-in Title

        }


        try {
            seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar1);

            audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            seekbar.setMax(audioManager
                    .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
            seekbar.setProgress(audioManager
                    .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));



            seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                            progress, 0);

                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        listview_nav = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_nav);
        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


        drawerListAdapter = new DrawerListAdapter(MainActivity.this, Items, images);
        listview_nav.setAdapter(drawerListAdapter);

        listview_nav.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if(position == 0){

                    Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ShowList_Activity.class);
                    startActivity(in);

                }else if(position == 1){

                }
            }


        });



        list_activity_check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                list_activity_check.setImageResource(R.drawable.playlist);
                mSmallBang.bang(v);
                mSmallBang.setmListener(new SmallBangListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd() {


                        Intent slideactivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EqualizerActivity.class);
                        slideactivity.putExtra("sessionvalue", intvalue);

                        Bundle bndlanimation =
                                ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.animate1, R.anim.animate2).toBundle();
                        startActivity(slideactivity, bndlanimation);

                    }
                });

            }


        });


        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                share.setImageResource(R.drawable.share_icon);
                mSmallBang.bang(v);
                mSmallBang.setmListener(new SmallBangListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd() {

                    }


                });

                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                        "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.digitamatix.mukilfm");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.digitamatix.mukilfm" + " Mukil FM shareApp");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));

            }
        });

        PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    //INCOMING call
                    //do all necessary action to pause the audio
                    if(mediaPlayer!=null){//check mp

                        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){

                            mediaPlayer.pause();
                        }
                    }

                    if(media!=null){//check mp

                        if(media.isPlaying()){

                            media.pause();
                        }
                    }



                } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    //Not IN CALL
                    //do anything if the phone-state is idle

                    if(mediaPlayer == null){//check mp

                        if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

                            mediaPlayer.start();
                        }
                    }
                    if(media==null){//check mp

                        if(!media.isPlaying()){

                            media.start();
                        }
                    }



                } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                    //A call is dialing, active or on hold
                    //do all necessary action to pause the audio
                    //do something here
                    if(mediaPlayer!=null){//check mp

                        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){

                            mediaPlayer.pause();
                        }
                    }
                    if(media!=null){//check mp

                        if(media.isPlaying()){

                            media.pause();
                        }
                    }



                }
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            }
        };//end PhoneStateListener


        TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if(mgr != null) {
            mgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }


    }



    private void addNotification() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mukil)
                        .setContentTitle("MUKIL FM")
                        .setContentText("Smartah Kelunga Ungal MukilFm");

        // Add as notification
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }

    class Player extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        private ProgressDialog progress;

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Boolean prepared;
            try {

                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(params[0]);
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        intialStage = true;
                        playPause = false;
                        control.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaPlayer.reset();

                    }
                });
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                prepared = true;
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("IllegarArgument", e.getMessage());
                prepared = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                prepared = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                prepared = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                prepared = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return prepared;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (progress.isShowing()) {
                progress.cancel();
            }
            Log.d("Prepared", "//" + result);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            media.stop();

            intialStage = false;
        }

        public Player() {
            progress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            this.progress.setMessage("Buffering...");
            media.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == 1001) {

                String result=data.getStringExtra("result");

                if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("STOP")){

                onStop();
                    finish();


            }else if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("Do Nothing")){


                    Toast.makeText(this, "Timer is not set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(media != null){
//            media.stop();  //Stops playback after playback has been stopped or paused
            media.release(); //Releases resources associated with this MediaPlayer object
            media = null;
        }
        if(mediaPlayer!= null){
//            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer= null;
        }
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {


        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Do you really want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                        MainActivity.this.finish();

                        mediaPlayer.release();
                        media.release();

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
    }
//        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

please help me in fixing this issues..
Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

In your onStop() of your activity stop and release the media player.

Place the below code in your **onStop()**:

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(media != null){
      media.stop();  //Stops playback after playback has been stopped or paused
      media.release(); //Releases resources associated with this MediaPlayer object
      media = null;
    }
    if(mediaPlayer!= null){
      mediaPlayer.stop();
      mediaPlayer.release();
      mediaPlayer= null;
    }
}
```

This is the proper way to stop media player.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Thq But remains same that my app is closing but starts and stops where it buffered last time and i have to start uo manually to play again for streaming current

Comment: Then I am very sure, you have problem somewhere else

Comment: can i send u full coding

Comment: posted bro please check it out